# Saving images in webapp

Tags: jsf, security

I have a web app which is saving uploaded images on the Server HD and retrieving it from there. My question is how secure is this approach? Will the server be vulnerable by implementing this approach? Alternatively, I have considered saving images bytearray in db as BLOB but I have experienced loads of problems retrieving images dynamically from db in JSF. Please help me in this, a little advise might be helpful.

I'm using:

- Glassfish 3.x
- JSF Mojarra 2.3.1
- EJB 3.0
- EclipseLink 2.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *My question is how secure is this approach?*

Depends on how **you** wrote the code.

---

> *Will the server be vulnerable by implementing this approach?*

As said, depends on how you wrote the code. If you're for example allowing the enduser to specify a random absolute path where to store or retrieve the file, then you've obviously a security hole.

---

> *Alternatively, I have considered saving images bytearray in db as BLOB but I have experienced loads of problems retrieving images dynamically from db in JSF.*

Just press `Ask Question` button on right top here and elaborate the concrete problem in detail and if the question is asked the smart way, you'll likely get answers how to fix the problem.